# Derivation of KVL for AC circuits

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, maxwell-equations

AC circuits have periodically changing current, due to which there will be a change in the magnetic flux as a consequence of which an electric field will be produced and hence an emf; my question is, whether this induced emf will invalidate the application of KVL for the loop or not? If not then any mathematical proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVL is valid for lumped circuits only.

One of the conditions that makes a circuit "lumped" is that the magnetic flux through the loops formed by the circuit wiring is negligible.

This is, of course, only an approximation, and in any real circuit KVL is not strictly correct. The approximation becomes less accurate as the physical extent of the circuit gets larger.

When the circuit size becomes comparable to the wavelength of the signals involved (say $l \gt 0.1 \lambda$) we can't really use the lumped circuit approximation any more and we have to start analyzing wires as transmission lines rather than ideal wires.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your last paragraph?

Comment: Just to add some ballpark estimation here, most circuits we deal with are gonna be less than 10m in size, with the possible exception, say, of an electrical substation. Looking at a 30m wavelength gives about 10 MHz as the frequency you start to worry about this sort of thing over. If we are talking mains power we are 6 orders of magnitude away from this limit, or even acoustic circuits we are 2 orders of magnitude away. But for computers and cell phones one can get much closer and optical light is way smaller.

Comment: There are whole books and university courses that elaborate on that last paragraph.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it that the magnetic flux $\Phi$ through the loop must be negligible, or is it that $\partial \Phi/ \partial t$ is negligible? As I understand it, KVL is an integral form of the Maxwell equation $\nabla \times E = - \partial B / \partial t$, which would lead to the second condition.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez Yeah you are correct, this sort of bias would usually come from an external magnetic field and we are assuming in KVL that the external magnetic field is unchanging, which is strictly speaking more general than just assuming it is zero. It would be much harder I think to engineer internal magnetic fields which change in tandem and thus cancel out on all possible loops.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez, if we're talking about the fields generated by an AC circuit itself, then it comes to the same thing. If we're talking about externally applied fields, then you're right, it's time-varying magnetic fields that could affect the circuit (but also, by superposition the effect of external magnetic fields won't change how the circuit responds to other sources).